# Importance of the bruise of Clementine in Eternal sunshine

Tags: plot-explanation, eternal-sunshine-of-spotless-mind

In the movie Eternal sunshine of spotless mind in one of the shots near the ending of the movie, Clementine looks in the mirror and sees a bruise on her thigh.

How did it happen?I didnt remember anything related to that bruise in the movie.Is it that because she fell in  the snow as shown in the initial portion of movie when she was with joel?Or anything else?

Comment: Its been a while since I've seen it but I think it was supposed to have happened while the Lacuna people were erasing her memories and partying...

Comment: @sanpaco Lacuna people partying is in between joel's therapy session.Clementine's therapy session is not shown in the movie.

Comment: yes but it is heavily implied and alluded to the fact that they have a habit of doing this during all memory removals.

Answer (score 2):

Mary then quits her job and steals the company's records, and mails the two former clients their records from Lacuna.

**The film returns to the present, after Joel and Clementine have met aboard the train.** They both come upon their Lacuna records later that day, and react with shock and bewilderment, because they have no clear memory of having known each other, let alone having had a relationship and having had their memories erased. Joel beckons Clementine to start over.

This above excerpt is from the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Sunshine_of_the_Spotless_Mind#Plot

There is no mention of this scene in IMDB but if you see the scenes its a mark of continuity for the audience to perceive the order of events. The mark is thus, from the fall on the hard frozen surface of the lake, Clementine took Joel after they met for the second time afresh in the train.

[image]

So you are correct on guessing which fall resulted in that wound or mark.